# Summing Up Number of Occurences of Values in a Range

Tags: excel

This should be incredibly straightforward. I have a column of values in Excel, and need to get the number of occurences of each value in some range; in this case:

- Above 70
- > = 60 && < 70
- > = 50 && < 60
- > = 40 && < 50
- < 40

The above 70 and below 40 were quite straightforward:

```
=COUNTIF(C2:C30, ">= 70")
=COUNTIF(C2:C30, "< 40")
```

I'm having trouble identifying values in the ranges between 60-69, 50-59, and 40-49. I have looked up some help and found a lot of it is for strings and substrings, but I'm working with whole numbers. 'Occurences in a range' may be ambiguous and I'm not getting quite the right keyword. So far I have tried:

```
=COUNT(IF(AND(C2:C30 >= 60, C2:C30 < 70), 1, 0))
```

So, count up the 1's IF they are between 60 - 69. This just returns 1 regardless of how many values in range there are in the column. I have also tried this with `SUM` in place of `COUNT` to the same effect.

Secondly, I tried:

```
=COUNTIF(C2:C30, IF(AND(>= 60, < 70), 1, 0))
```

I assumed that the COUNTIF was just a loop under the hood, and that it would iterate over the values in the column and the IF/AND would figure that out. Apparently not. Next, I tried putting the range to be tested inside the `AND` and summing the resulting 1's and 0's, with the same assumption:

```
=SUM(IF(AND(C2:C30>=60,C2:C30<70), 1, 0))
```

And this also returns just `1`, too, regardless of how many values there are in range in the column.

I should say I read my spreadsheet into R and did this in seconds, but I need to give this to someone else who only uses Excel. That there are people like that in a world of Python/R/MATLAB baffles me, but here we are - help very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for `COUNTIFS()`?

Comment: @JvdV Ah, I had looked at that but I thought that each range had to be distinct (i.e., `A1:A10` in one `B1:B10` in the next, etc.) - my oversight, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try these out these should work properly.

```
= COUNTIF(B:B, ">= 50") - COUNTIF(B:B, "> 59")
=COUNTIF(B:B, ">= 60") - COUNTIF(B:B, "> 69")
=COUNTIF(B:B, "  >= 40") + COUNTIF(B:B, "< 50")
```